# Finding a classmember in a vector of other class members

Tags: c++

I have the classes Team and Player. Every Team member has an object vector playerlist with his players stored in. Every player now has some attributes like ID. Now i want to transfer a Player to a Team . So i created a function for this.

First i want to findout if the Player b maybe is already a member of Team a, in which case a message should be printed out. But i failed in writing a function which does this.

Here is my try(the search starts in the if loop, where i want to find out if Player b is member of Team a)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:

private:


};

class Team
{
public:


    vector<Player> getplayerlist(){
        return playerlist;
    }
    string getteamname(){
        return teamname;
    }
    void playerbuy(Team a, Player b)
    {
        vector<Player> playerlist;
        playerlist = a.getplayerlist();
        if (find(playerlist.begin(), playerlist.end(), 5) != playerlist.end()) {

        }
        else {
            cout << "This player is not member of " << a.getteamname();
        }
    }

private:
    vector<Player> playerlist;
    string teamname;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;

}
```

I got the error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Player' (or there is no acceptable conversion). I figured out i comes from the line

```
if (find(playerlist.begin(), playerlist.end(), 5) != playerlist.end())
```

The =! playerlist.end() seems to be wrong there. This part of the code is some copy of another code so i don't know what it does. What should i put in there instead ?
And what does the 5 means ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is giving you a good hint: you need to implement an equality operator for class `Player`. That is what `std::find` uses to determine if an element has been found.

Alternatively, you can use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a custom unary predicate.

Comment: thx i tried that and failed... if (find_if(spielerliste.begin(), spielerliste.end(), [c](Spieler const& n){
  return n.getID()== c;                               But this failed with : IntelliSense: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function

Comment: @jimbo999 How did it fail? And do you have C++11 support?

Comment: i have visual basic studio 2013 which should have some support, but i dont know for sure how to find out ? sorry im really new into this stuff

Comment: @jimbo999 I don't use VS so I'm not sure. But it looks like you need to make the `getID()` method `const` (look up "const member function".)