# Stop Code instead of break with a Error Message

Tags: c++

Here is some code that is from a great website which does what i want quite well (searching in a vector of class objects by addressing the class objects).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>



using namespacestd;

class class1
{
private:
    int id;
    double value;

public:
    class1(int i, double v) :id(i), value(v){ }
    int getId()const { return id; }
    double getValue() const { return value; }
};

class HasIdentifier :public unary_function<class1, bool>
{
public:
    HasIdentifier(int id) : m_id(id) { }
    bool operator()(const class1& c)const
    {
        return (c.getId() == m_id);
    }
private:
    int m_id;
};


class class2
{
private:
    vector <class1> objects;
public:
    class2()
    {
        objects.push_back(class1(1, 100.0));
        objects.push_back(class1(2, 100.0));
        objects.push_back(class1(3, 100.0));
    }

    double GetValueOfId(int id)
    {
        vector<class1>::iterator itElem = find_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(),  HasIdentifier(id));
        return itElem->getValue();
    }
};

int main() {

    class2 c;

    int id = 4;

    cout << id << " " << c.GetValueOfId(id);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It works well but whenenver i put "int id ">3 it crashes because object only has the size 3. I got this, but is there a possibility to get warned when this will happen so that is does not crash but im able to correct it somehow in the code with a warn message?

Comment: You mean, "I have a bunch of stuff, and when people ask me for something, I give it to them. My world collapses when they ask me for something I don't have."

Comment: Yes by checking the returned interator for correctness and throwing an exception if invalid?

Comment: @KerrekSB What *is* the recommendation for? Seems out of place to me.

Comment: @BlueIce: Learn to say "No"!

Comment: `find_if` will return the iterator if search is successful or else will return `iterator after the last element`. You can try 
`if(itElem != objects.end()) return itElem->getValue();
 else return -1
`

Comment: @jimbo999 _'nice and funny'_ Yeah, so here we go, goodbye ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And this week, in Stack Overflow comedy, we present...

Comment: Check the returned iterator, as you were doing in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309057/finding-a-classmember-in-a-vector-of-other-class-members).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the returned iterator for validness and throw and exception (or report an error any other way) if it is invalid:

```
if (itElem == objects.end())
    throw MyVeryCoolException("Woops wrong id");
```

Dont forget to set up a global exception handler (toplevel catch), otherwise your application will still crash if the exception is uncaught.